# Angular2/cli code not running in IE

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have my angular2 code that is built using angular-cli which runs absolutely fine in Chrome. The same application doesn't run on IE. My tsconfig.json is as below. Are there any other things that I need to take care of.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: your question is missing a lot of things: which version of IE? the version of CLI generated the project? anything shows in the console?

Comment: IE 11, Angular CLI "1.0.0-rc.0", there are no error shown in the console. I don't see polyfills.ts file in my project. Is that causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running polyfill.ts file that has scripts for old browsers.

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```